# Is there an alternative to use of the method Array#product?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am using the method `Array#product` with several arguments that are large arrays. The receiver is also a large array. Consequently, the resulting array is huge and consumes an excessive amount of memory. I need all the combinations produced but I don't need them in a single array.

I would like to know if there is an alternative to using that method that requires less memory. Computational time is not really an issue.

Comment: There might be alternatives.  How much variation is there in your input data? How large are we talking about when you say "rather large" ?

Comment: https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/permutation When you say all possible combinations, does order matter? If it does, maybe the permutation method would be better suited for you.

Comment: Likewise, if order does not matter and you do actually mean combination, here’s a method that returns all combinations of an array’s values. https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/combination

Comment: Oh, I should mention. I’ve listed these methods because their C implementations are likely a lot more efficient than whatever you’re doing (assuming they can accomplish the same goal).

Comment: Since you tagged this with ActiveRecord, you should share your database schema / models. It is usually much better to perform expensive calculations in the database before they ever hit Ruby.

Comment: Richard, I trust that you don't mind my edit to your question. Is what I wrote accurate? In any event, it's your question so please edit it as you see fit. I think it's a good question, so I hope it will be reopened. It's a little unusual to see a question that's been closed having 4 upvotes (and 1 downvote). Most closed questions only have downvotes.

Comment: Richard, kindly reply to my question: "Is what I wrote accurate?".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the block form of `product` (see https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/product).

For example the following makes my ruby process unresponsive and I have to `kill -9` it:

```
list = Array.new(100_000)
list.product list
```

However with the block form I can `control+c` to stop it any time:

```
list.product(list) do |combination|
  puts combination.join(",")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me begin with the problem of computing the product of two arrays. Later I will address the more general problem.

```
arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [4,5,6]

arr1.product(arr2)
  #=> [[1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 4], [2, 5],
  #    [2, 6], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
```

To reduce memory requirements--that is, avoiding the construction of the above array--you can construct an enumerator.

```
product_enum = Enumerator.new do |y|
  arr1.size.times do |i|
    e1 = arr1[i]
    arr2.size.times { |j| y << [e1, arr2[j]] }
  end
end
  #=> #<Enumerator: 3<Enumerator::Generator:0x00...20>:each>

loop do
  p product_enum.next
end
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[1, 6]
[2, 4]
[2, 5]
[2, 6]
[3, 4]
[3, 5]
[3, 6]
```

To reuse the enumerator execute `product_enum.rewind`. See [Enumerator::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-c-new) and [Enumerator#rewind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind). `Enumerator::new`'s block variable `y` is called a *yielder*. An enumerator can be thought of as a machine that generates values following certain rules.

Ruby's methods [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-combination), [Array#permutation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-permutation) and others return enumerators, but for reasons that are unknown to me, [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-product) returns an array. (Perhaps a reader can explain why in a comment.)

We can construct an `Array` method `product_enum` that returns an enumerator, which you could use for your problem.

```
class Array
  def product_enum(*arr)
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      self.size.times do |i|
        e1 = self[i]
        product_enum_recurse(y,[e1],*arr)
      end
    end
  end

  def product_enum_recurse(y,a,*arr)
    v, *rest = arr
    v.size.times do |i|
      if rest.empty?
        y << [*a, v[i]]
      else
        product_enum_recurse(y,[*a, v[i]],*rest)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
e = [1,2].product_enum([3,4], [5,6], [7,8])
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00...0>:each> 

loop do
  p e.next
end
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 3, 5, 8]
[1, 3, 6, 7]
[1, 3, 6, 8]
[1, 4, 5, 7]
[1, 4, 5, 8]
[1, 4, 6, 7]
[1, 4, 6, 8]
[2, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 8]
[2, 3, 6, 7]
[2, 3, 6, 8]
[2, 4, 5, 7]
[2, 4, 5, 8]
[2, 4, 6, 7]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```